# How to get the All Public Route in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

How to get all the public route only

```
  Route::getRoutes()
```

Get all route but need only public route

Comment: explain in more details. Show with an example what you need.

Answer (score 2):

There is no exact way to do this because the concept of "public" is dependent on your specific implementation. What is "public"? Is it a route without certain middleware, etc.

Depending on your requirements, extending the following function would work:

```
// loop over each route, and if it has 1 or more middleware's, 
// reject it, leaving you with just the "public" routes
// You can change the condition to what is public
// very easily
$routesWithoutMiddleware = collect(Route::getRoutes())->reject(function($route) {
    return count($route->middleware()) > 0;
});
```

Comment: default middleware  is guest, so count>1 then works @chris

Comment: No worries. If you feel like this works for your particular question, make sure to mark it correct for future readers of the question/answer